# Setup enum control in Unity custom inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I want to setup an enum control in unity custom inspector. But for some reason my enum control is not changing its value on selection. Here is my code.

For anyone who wants to understand the context from screenshot or code, I am integrating Facebook sdk and need to add permission using custom editor.

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        ShowCurrentPermissions();

        FacebookPermissions permission = FacebookPermissions.none;
        permission = (FacebookPermissions)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Permission", permission);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add Permission"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Add pressed");
            permission = (FacebookPermissions)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Permission", permission);
            AddPermission(permission);
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Remove Permission"))
        {
            permission = (FacebookPermissions)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Permission", permission);
            RemovePermission(permission);
        }
    }
```

The enum control is not responding at all, but the buttons are working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `FacebookPermissions permission = FacebookPermissions.none;` statement to the `Awake()` or `Start()` function. Or at the very least, move it outside of the scope of your `OnInspectorGUI()`

Just like the regular `OnGUI()` function `OnInspectorGUI()` is called several times a frame. Effectively resetting the enum back to the value you are giving to it.